# Tikz: arrows are exceeding the limit of rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am having some issues with Tikz package. My intention is to build a diagram. However, some of the arrows are exceeding the limits of the rectangles, and that makes the image really awful (highlighted in red below).

Does someone know how to fix this? I have already tried to add some opacity to the rectangle filling color, but it does not make any difference.

Please find my code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\tikzstyle{caixa} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3 cm, minimum height=1.8cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white, thick, text=black, text opacity=1, fill opacity=0]
\tikzstyle{fantasma} = [rectangle, text centered, draw=white, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{seta} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{tracejada} = [thick,->,>=stealth, dashed]
\tikzstyle{linha} = [thick,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, auto, >=latex', scale=1.2\textwidth]
        \node (egressos) [caixa, anchor=west, text width=3cm] {\textbf{Egressos do ensino médio de 16--22 anos}};
        \node (semchave) [caixa, above of=egressos, text width=3cm, xshift=4cm] {\textbf{Sem chave de identificação}};
        \node (comchave) [caixa, below of=egressos, text width=3cm, xshift=4cm] {\textbf{Com chave de identificação}};
        \node (semenem) [caixa, above of=comchave, text width=3cm, xshift=4cm] {\textbf{Não participantes do Enem}};
        \node (comenem) [caixa, below of=comchave, text width=3cm, xshift=4cm] {\textbf{Participantes do Enem}};
        \node (naoingresso) [caixa, right of=semenem, text width=3cm, xshift=2.5cm] {\textbf{Não ingressantes do ensino superior}};
        \node (ingresso) [caixa, right of=comenem, text width=3cm, xshift=2.5cm] {\textbf{Ingressantes do ensino superior}};
        
        \node (1) [fantasma, below of=egressos, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 1.754.615};
        \node (2) [fantasma, below of=semchave, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 57.386};
        \node (3) [fantasma, below of=comchave, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 1.697.229};
        \node (4) [fantasma, below of=semenem, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 581.299};
        \node (5) [fantasma, below of=comenem, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 1.115.930};
        \node (6) [fantasma, below of=naoingresso, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 776.025};
        \node (7) [fantasma, below of=ingresso, yshift=1.2cm] {N = 921.204};
        
        \node (8) [fantasma, left=0.1cm of semchave, yshift=2mm] {3,3\%};
        \node (9) [fantasma, left=0.1cm of comchave, yshift=-2mm] {96,7\%};
        \node (10) [fantasma, left=0.1cm of semenem, yshift=2mm] {34,2\%};
        \node (11) [fantasma, left=0.1cm of comenem, yshift=-2mm] {65,8\%};
        
        \node [coordinate] (joint1) [right of=egressos, node distance=2.0cm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (joint2) [right of=comchave, node distance=2.0cm, yshift=-0.2mm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (joint3) [right of=semenem, node distance=2.1cm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (joint4) [right of=comenem, node distance=2.4cm, yshift=-0.39mm]{};
        
        \draw[linha] (egressos) -- (joint1);
        \draw[seta] (joint1) |- (semchave);
        \draw[seta] (joint1) |- (comchave);
        \draw[linha] (comchave.east) -- (joint2);
        \draw[seta] (joint2) |- (semenem);
        \draw[seta] (joint2) |- (comenem);
        \draw[linha] (semenem.east) -- (joint3);
        \draw[tracejada] (joint3) |- node[above, very near end] {74,9\%} (naoingresso.155);
        \draw[tracejada] (joint3) |- node[above, very near end] {25,1\%} (ingresso.155);
        \draw[linha] (comenem.east) -- (joint4);
        \draw[seta] (joint4) |- node[below, pos=0.85] {30,6\%} (naoingresso.208);
        \draw[seta] (joint4) |- node[below, pos=0.85] {69,4\%} (ingresso.208);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the image:

[image]

Comment: After compilation of thecode I didn't get those unwanted exceeding lines. Maybe the issue comes from the pdf viewer you are using.

Comment: Plus I think you should have typed `fill opacity=1` whether your idea were not to see what is behind the node.

Comment: Another way to draw the lines is like this: \draw (name1) --++(0.5,0) -| (name2); Such line starts at node name1 goes 0.5 to the right and hits perpendicular node name2. The joint coordinate nodes aren't necessary anymore and you draw a uninterrupted line stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your document example is not possible to reproduce showed images. Showed image is not produced by provided code.

Anyway, your image code can be rewrite into concise and much shorter code which consider recent syntax for defining of common picture elements styles, use positioning syntax defined in `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{ 
       caixa/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, thick,  
                       minimum height=15mm, text width=28mm, 
                       align=flush center, font=\bfseries},
 every label/.style = {font=\small},
          el/.style = {font=\small, pos=1, anchor=#1 east}, 
        seta/.style = {thick,-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}},
%\tikzstyle{tracejada} = [thick,->,>=stealth, dashed]
%\tikzstyle{linha} = [thick,>=stealth]
        }
        
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 4mm and 8mm,  
                        ]
\node (egressos)   [caixa,
                    label=below:{$N = 1.754.615$}
                    ]   {Egressos do ensino médio de 16--22 anos};
\node (semchave)   [caixa, 
                    label=below:{$N = 57.386$},
                    above right=of egressos
                    ]   {Sem chave de identificação};
\node (comchave)    [caixa, 
                     label=below:{$N = 1.697.229$},
                     below right=of egressos,
                     ]  {Com chave de identificação};
\node (semenem)     [caixa, 
                     label=below:{$N = 581.299$},
                     above right=of comchave
                     ] {Não participantes do Enem};
\node (comenem)     [caixa, 
                     label=below:{$N = 581.299$},
                     below right=of comchave
                     ]  {Participantes do Enem};
\node (naoingresso) [caixa, 
                     label=below:{$N = 1.115.930$},
                     right=18mm of semenem
                     ]  {Não ingressantes do ensino superior};
\node (ingresso)    [caixa, 
                     label=below:{$N = 776.025$},
                     at={(comenem -| naoingresso)}
                     ]  {Ingressantes do ensino superior};
% conection between nodes
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style=seta]
\draw   (egressos.east) -- ++ (0.3,0) coordinate (join1)
                        |- (semchave) node[el=south] {\SI{3.3}{\%}}; 
\draw   (join1.east)    |- (comchave) node[el=north] {\SI{96.7}{\%}};

\draw   (comchave.east) -- ++ (0.3,0) coordinate (join2)
                        |- (semenem) node[el=south] {\SI{34.2}{\%}};
\draw   (join2.east)    |- (comenem) node[el=north] {\SI{65.8}{\%}};

\draw   (comenem.east)  -- ++ (0.6,0) coordinate (join3)
                        |- (naoingresso) node[el=north] {\SI{30.6}{\%}};
\draw   (join3.east)    |- (ingresso)    node[el=north] {\SI{69.4}{\%}};
% dashed
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={seta, dashed},
                  transform canvas={yshift=2ex}]
\draw   (semenem.east)  -- ++ (0.3,0) coordinate (join3)
                        |- (naoingresso) node[el=south] {\SI{74.9}{\%}};
\draw   (join3.east)    |- (ingresso)    node[el=south] {\SI{25.1}{\%}};
    \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]